# Formatted hdd but grub remains, can't boot from cd or install windows

Tags: boot

I bought a laptop with Ubuntu formatted the hdd through my PC put the hdd back wiped out formatted still grub remains can't let me boot from windows cd or USB !! What can I do.?

Comment: The boot disc is not running can not get trough grub not with a win cd not with win ISO or Ubuntu cd I can not find my answer!

Comment: You need a Windows Repair or Installation disk. And for booting from CD/USB you should change the boot order in your BIOS>

Comment: I did change the boot order still grub coming on I tried several install and repair cd what were working on my other laptop with no problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the BIOS on the laptop to change the boot order.  Often you can press a key (listed during boot, F12?) to enable a one time boot option, select USB or CD.

Comment: Done that million time already tried with cd a bootable USB stick changing up the boot settings in the bios